# MySQL spatial data types in dapper.net core

Tags: mysql, .net-core, dapper

Trying to find any reference to utilising the spatial data types in dapper.net from .net core.

We're using `point` and `polygon` in our database however are unable to find anything that eludes to what data type to use in the models codeside.

Answer (score 1):

Try the MySqlGeometry Class:

```
    public byte[] Location { get; set; }

    public MySqlGeometry LocationAsGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            var geo = new MySqlGeometry(MySqlDbType.Geometry, Location);
            return geo;
        }
    }
```